# enhanced for loop does not invoke the overriden methods of arraylist. Classcast exception

Tags: java, for-loop

**Env: JDK 7**

```
 {
   JSONArray refJSONArray = getSomeJSON. --returns a json array.
   for (Serializable refJSON : refJSONArray);  
 }
```

`JSONArray` is a customized .

```
  {
     public class JSONArray extends ArrayList<Serializable> 
  }
```

It is an `arraylist` of serialized  objects . 
I have overriden the get method of `Arraylist` and have custom logic to covert few objects.

This piece of code worked well on `jdk 6`.

we have recently uprgraded to `jdk 7` and we obtain a `class cast exception`.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to mypackage.utils.JSONObject.
```

**Obsrevations :** a normal for loop

```
    { 
        for (int i=0 ; i<jsonarray; i ++)
    }
```

This does invoke the overridden `GET` method and does the required conversions.

On replacing the legacy for loop to enhanced loop. The overridden methods are not being invoked.

I wonder why ?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It's very unclear what's going on at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the effects of

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    final JSONObject o = list.get(i);
    ...
}
```

With the following

```
for (JSONObject o : list) { ... }
```

And you say your customized `ArrayList` only overrides `get`.

The above paints a perfectly consistent picture because enhanced for loop expands into

```
for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
   final JOSNObject o = it.next();
   ...
}
```

Therefore it doesn't involve the `get` method of `ArrayList`.

Fix this  by overriding the `iterator()` method of `ArrayList`, which now must supply a customized `Iterator`.

FYI if you were on Java 8, this would be elegantly solved with a Streams expression.

Comment: Awesomeness. Thank you.